# Shell Script (AIX) : Extracting OS and browser information from user agent string

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

i get user agent information like below in a log file.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11)
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28
```

i would like to get OS and browser information from each user agent. Please suggest me how we can achieve this in shell script(AIX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
case $user_agent in
  *MSIE*) browser=MSIE ;;
  *Chrome*) browser=Chrome ;;
  ....
  *) echo "Cannot extract browser from [[$user_agent]]" >2 ;;
esac
case $user_agent in
  *Windows*) plarform=Windows ;;
  *Linux*) platform=Linux ;;
  ....
  *) echo "Cannot extract platform from [[$user_agent]]" >2 ;;
esac
```

You will have to go through a few iterations adding cases for various browsers (there is no uniformity there).

Comment: Thanks so much. I am using AIX and have #!/bin/bash in my script file. It throws syntax error saying extra ')' symbol. Tried other syntax too. Nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions please ??

Comment: Try searching for the extra ")" or missing ";;". Try removing clauses to isolate the fault. If all else fails, post your script in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. i was trying to use this with awk script. i am not sure whats wrong in that. I changed my code to while do loop. Its fine now.